# Count Non-Blank Cells in Column

Tags: excel, vba

Is there an alternative method to counting a column's non-blank cells than the below method? The method below does the trick, but when there is no data in the column, the script generates an `No Cells Were Found Error`. Looking for a script that just returns 0 in the event of no cells instead of the error.

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A30000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count`

Comment: [`COUNTA` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Count Non-Blank or Non-Empty Cells in a Column

- The code was used in a new workbook. In `Sheet1`, in cell `A2` I entered the formula `=""` and in cell `A3` I entered a single quote (`'`). These two cells appear to be empty, but they are not. They are blank.

```vb
Sub CountNonBlanks()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A30000")

    ' Counts cells that are not empty, do not contain a formula
    ' that evaluates to an empty string (e.g. '=""')
    ' and do not contain a single quote.
    Dim NonBlanks As Long
    NonBlanks = rg.Cells.Count - Application.CountBlank(rg)
    
    ' Counts cells that are not empty.
    Dim NonEmpties As Long
    NonEmpties = Application.CountA(rg)

    Debug.Print rg.Address(0, 0), NonBlanks, NonEmpties

End Sub
```

- The result in the Immediate window was:

  ```
  A2:A30000      0             2
  ```